# What s wrong with the polygons of my model

Tags: modeling

why are all those polygons transparent in my model?[image]

Comment: Probably your faces normals : in edit mode, select all and Ctrl+N. But hard to see well in this front ortho view. You should share your blend file in order to check what is wrong. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is the normals on you faces have flipped.  This will sometimes happen when you scale a mesh negatively or you extrude a face in a negative direction local to the face.  One way to see these faces is by disabling backface culling.  But I would not recommend this, because all it does is makes both sides of the faces visible in the viewport.  When you render you will still get dark looking faces.  For a permanent fix, go into Edit Mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces.  Then select recalculate normals under Shading/UVs in the tool bar, or just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]